# How to deploy multiple charms on the bootstrapped node or on a single node?

Tags: cloud, juju, wordpress

I've been wondering if it is possible to deploy a charm, say for example, a wordpress charm to a single node.
i.e. bootstrapped node + mysql node + wordpress node = 1 node

One scenario can be: deployments that do not require high availability and get very little traffic.

Answer (score 1):

If you're just looking to run a personal blog and want to save money you can run all of this on a single node, here's an entire single node installation from scratch

```
juju bootstrap
juju deploy --to 0 wordpress
juju deploy --to 0 mysql
juju add-relation wordpress mysql 
juju expose wordpress
```

This will run everything on one node, however we still have the flexibility to grow horizontally. If your blog gets more traffic and you need to scale:

```
juju add-unit wordpress
```

Since we're omitting the `--to` command Juju will fire up a new dedicated machine for Wordpress and relate it. You can also `remove-unit` when the surge is over and go back to a cheaper one node set up.

The `--to` command lets you do a bunch of options for deploying to units, you can check it out in the Deploying section of the documentation here:

- https://jujucharms.com/docs/stable/charms-deploying

Answer (score 0):

You can also use jitsu, jitsu is the tool where they develop new ideas how juju should work. Jitsu has a "deploy-to" command.